# Why Docker container exits with exec format error?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, dockerhub

I use the following dockerfile. It's about an aspcore7 web application.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication3.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication3.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```

The application configuration is like so

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>81f43918-ec08-492f-91d0-94f7160b54d5</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I use the following settings upon publish to the DockerHub

[image]

The runtime is set to `linux-arm64`

When uploaded the os/architecture is displayed as `linux/amd64` and not as `linux-arm64`

Finally when the container starts, it exits with the error

```
exec /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Is this error related to the architecture? If this one is true, why i have different architecture upon publisihng?

PS: The container is hosted within a raspberry pi4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry has `arm` architecture. Docker images built on `x86-64` won't run there.
There are `arm` Docker images in [Linux arm64 Tags section here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet). You need to build it using [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/).

Comment: Thanks! docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 did the trick